# Both Default parameters set giving error/

Tags: c++

In my ".h" file , I have defined :

```
    example(CQueue* queue = NULL, double code = 0);
```

In 2  different methods of my ".cpp" file, I  have to use :

```
    example(queue);

    example(code2);
```

I get errors in both cases. I didnt want to overload. Is defining it :

```
    example(CQueue* queue, double code = 0);
```

the only way? or can I define it the way it is currently defined?

Comment: First should work, second shouldn't. What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: error: arguement of type double is incompatible with parameter of type cqueue*. But what is wrong with my current definition in .h?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your .h file. your example(code2) causes this error, because as others have already said, you can't just use the rightmost parameter without specifying all parameters behind it. This is why your first example works, queue is something and the 2nd argument defaults to 0.

Comment: It's hard to give you a good answer when you've already given the optimum answer (overload) and said that you don't want to use it. There are ways to fake overloading, and they might be the solution you're looking for, but they're worse than overloading, so you might just think "that's worse". It would help a lot to understand why you don't want to overload. That way, we can either find a way to overload that doesn't cause the issues that make you not want to overload or convince you that overloading really is the best way if the reasons make no sense. **Why don't you want to overload?**

Comment: overloading is not an accepted coding way! I currently have it defined it this way: example( CQueue* queue, double code = 0);  for  the .cpp, I have passed: example(queue); and example(NULL, code2);. Looks like this is the best solution.

Comment: @user1563551: Why do you think that? Sounds like dogma to me. Especially since overloading is the solution to your problem. In any case default arguments are just a different form of overloading, so if you accept default arguments then I cannot see why you won't accept overloading.

Comment: @user1563551: Accepted by who or what? Do you really like `x.setInt(y); x.addInt(z);` better than `x = y + z;` (Which, assuming you need to use more than just integers, only works if you overload `=` and `+`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can define it like that, but don't expect the second call to work. The first one should be fine, provided `queue` is a `CQueue*`. If it's an object, you'll need to pass its address: `&queue`.

You'll have to change the second call to:

```
example(NULL, code2);
```

or, as you said, overload.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a specific value for `code`, you **must** also pass a value for the earlier optional parameters, even if they're given default values in the method signature.

Just explicitly pass what you've defined as the default value: `example(NULL, code2);`

Your definition is fine, but if you want to be able to also call `example(code2)` then you **must** overload.

`example(queue);` should work depending on the declaration of `queue`.